# How to find all onDelete clauses with 'Restrict' value from a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, clause

I need to find and fix all the `onDelete` clauses of foreign keys, on a `MySQL` database, because all of them are now by default `RESTRICT`.

Can this be done by a MySQL-query?

At least to find all the foreign keys

**UPDATE after @peterm answer:**

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.`REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` 
WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = '%database_name%' AND delete_rule = 'RESTRICT';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/referential-constraints-table.html)

> The REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS table provides information about foreign keys.

`DELETE_RULE` field is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To find all Foreign Keys in a database table, you may want to attempt the following SQL query:

```
use INFORMATION_SCHEMA;

select TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME,
REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME from KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where
REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = '<mytable>';
```

Or you could also try executing the following query to show how the table was created:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE <mytable>;
```